# How to update a group of rows by a criteria of one row in the same table

Tags: sql, self-join

I have to update the status field of a group of rows in one table. The criteria is only in one row.

Example:

```
ID    Name    No   Status
 1    CR100   4711   1
 2    CR100   4712   0
 3    CR100   4713   0

 4    CR101   4712   0
 5    CR101   4713   0

 6    CR102   4715   0
 7    CR102   4788   1
 8    CR102   4733   0
```

I want to update the status in all rows of the Group where at least one status is 1. In my example the status in rows of the group CR100 and CR102 have to be upated. to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use an UPDATE query similar to the following:

```
update yt
set status = 1
where exists (select name
              from yt t1
              where status = 1
                 and yt.name = t1.name);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6a79/1)